# Permissions required for Google Partners API?

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to get a list of companies from the Google Partners API using python. I Should be able to use [these methods](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/partners/v2/python/latest/), in particular `companies().list()` but I keep getting an error

> HttpError 403  "The caller does not have permission"

The code I am trying to use:

```
import pprint
import httplib2
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/partners'
client_secret = 'mysecret' 
api_key       = 'mykey'
client_id     = 'mycid'

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id, client_secret, scope)

def main():

storage = Storage('credentials7.dat')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, tools.argparser.parse_args())

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('partners', 'v2', developerKey=api_key, http=http)

try:

    # The Calendar API's events().list method returns paginated results, so we
    # have to execute the request in a paging loop. First, build the
    # request object. The arguments provided are:
    #   primary calendar for user
    request = service.companies().list()
    # Loop until all pages have been processed.
    while request != None:
        # Get the next page.
        response = request.execute()
        # Accessing the response like a dict object with an 'items' key
        # returns a list of item objects (events).
        for event in response.get('items', []):
        # The event object is a dict object with a 'summary' key.
            print event
        # Get the next request object by passing the previous request object to
        # the list_next method.
        request = service.events().list_next(request, response)

except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    # The AccessTokenRefreshError exception is raised if the credentials
    # have been revoked by the user or they have expired.
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
           'the application to re-authorize')




if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

the above code is modified from a calendar example so there may be other problems. The permissions error however comes on line 41: `response = request.execute()` and is what I am worried about right now.

On my google developers console I have enabled the Partners API, and made the Auth 2.0 Credentials of type other.

I am stumped as to why I don't have permission to access what I believe is public data.

Thanks

Comment: Has it popped up and requested access? The user you log in with needs to have access to it.   you are also supplying api_key which is only for public apis I wonder if you are confusing it.

Comment: Yes it pops up and I can log in but I still get the error. Yea I realize I don't need the API key. I tried it with just the key got the error, tried it with auth 2.0 and still got the error. I was out of ideas so I just tried with both and thats the code I posted here