# Google Partners API Permission Denied

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm having the same issue as the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215631/permissions-required-for-google-partners-api).

Unfortunately, that project was put on hold and the question was never answered. Does anyone know why an authenticated call to `https://partners.googleapis.com/v2/companies?key=API_KEY` returns the following?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of data you are querying for, it may be necessary to use OAuth 2.0 instead of just an API key. If the data you are querying is entirely public, though, you may be ok with just your API key.

Either way, https://developers.google.com/partners/v2/how-tos/authorizing appears to explain what is necessary to set up auth for this method correctly.

Comment: Thanks @John. I started implementing OAuth 2.0 but got stuck very quickly. What am I supposed to put for the "Authorized javascript origins" and "Authorized redirect uris" part in Google Developers Console? Where is the scope url supposed to go? Also, when and where do I get to the consent screen to authorize the API? How do I get the access token and can I then put it in the API call as a query term?

Comment: The authorized origins or authorized redirect uris are based on what page you are executing this query from (assuming you are running it client-side). The scope url goes in the "scopes" in your OAuth authorization call. The consent screen should be shown when you request authorization; this will vary depending on your approach. The access token is the result of the user granting OAuth permission, and this should be passed in the "Authorization" header as a "Bearer" token.